# Format of a reference in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am writing my thesis and using `biblatex`. The journal papers appear as:

```
H. Zhang and S. Wang. “Linearly constrained global optimization via piecewise-
linear approximation”. In: Journal of Computational and 
Applied Mathematics 214.1 (Apr. 2008), pp. 111–120.
```

However, I want the reference to appear as

```
H. Zhang and S. Wang. “Linearly constrained global optimization via piecewise-
linear approximation”. In: Journal of Computational and 
Applied Mathematics vol. 214 no. 1, pp. 111–120 April 2008.
```

Here is the compilable files

```
\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper, 12 pt]{ucr}
\usepackage{setspace}   %%%%  for double sizing 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,color,graphicx, amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{.14cm}

\usepackage[style=numeric,
        hyperref=true,
        url=false,
        isbn=false,
        backref=false,
        citereset=chapter,
        maxcitenames=3,
        maxbibnames=100,
        block=none]{biblatex}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol.  #1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\addnbspace no.   #1}

\addbibresource{Bib_Files/Thesis_Bib_File.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
 bibliography = {Bibliography},
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% For Double Spacing 
\makeatletter
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother
\setstretch{1.667}
%%%%%%%%For Double Spacing 


\title{Tile}
\author{Author}
\degreemonth{June}
\degreeyear{Year}
\degree{Degree}

\chair{Chair}

\maketitle
\copyrightpage{}
\approvalpage{}

\degreesemester{Spring}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{acknowledgements}


\end{acknowledgements}

\begin{dedication}
\null\vfil
{\large
\begin{center}
To my parents.
\end{center}}
\vfil\null
\end{dedication}

\input{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{doublespace}

\graphicspath{{chapter1/}}
\input{chapter1/ICC2012}

\graphicspath{{chapter2/}}
\input{chapter2/ICC2012}

\graphicspath{{chapter3/}}
\input{chapter3/proof}

\graphicspath{{chapter4/}}
\input{chapter4/Risk_Managment}


\end{doublespace}


\begin{singlespace}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{singlespace}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I add some notes to describe how I make the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I added the main  tex file. However, for compiling this file, a `.bib` file and four chapters are needed. Should I upload them as well?

Comment: Yes, my question was resolved by @Alan Muun link.

Comment: Should I delete this post?